# optional extension in expressjs route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I want to have an optional extension, like `.xml` or `.csv` or `.json` (the default, no extensions would return json).

```
app.get('/days-ago/:days(.:ext)?', function(req, res) {
```

This doesn't appear to work, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
GET /days-ago/7.xml
GET /days-ago/7.csv
GET /days-ago/7.json
GET /days-ago/7
```

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you are using wrong pattern for the route. Here is the corrected one:

```
app.get('/days-ago/:days\.:ext?', function(req, res) {
```

Therefore, to achieve your goal I would create a middleware that checks for the empty parameter and sets it to the desired one

Something like this:

```
var defaultParamMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.params.ext) {
        req.params.ext = 'json';
    }

    next();
};

app.get('/days-ago/:days\.:ext?', defaultParamMiddleware, function (req, res) {
    res.json(req.params);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a real regex: `app.get(/\/days-ago\/\w+(\.\w+)?/), function (req, res {...` (or similar). The route parameter built-in grammar is pretty limited. It may actually be able to express what you need, but I don't see the point when regexs are built into the language and well understood.

Comment: how do I get the parameters?

Comment: req.params is an array of them